# How to consume protobuff in Spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, protocol-buffers

I have a problem to consume a converted protobuff message to a Spring boot micro service.

I tried with below  statement in Rest controller, but didn't work.

```
@PostMapping(value = EndPoint.TRANS_HANDLER, consumes = "application/x-protobuf", produces ="application/x-protobuf")
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have a GRPC client calling a GRPC service for this?

Comment: Thank you for the direction as I'm working on this further.

Answer (score 0):

One way to consume (and transmit in general) protobufs in microcontrollers is using GRPC calls. The caller microservice would have a GRPC client which allows it to send a call to your GRPC service.

The service would look something like this:

```
@Override
public void getResponse(RequestProto request, StreamObserver<ResponseProto> responseObserver) {

    try {
                    //Logic to produce the proto response
                    responseObserver.onNext(responseProto);
                }
        );

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //handle exception
    } finally {
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }
}
```

The client would send a GRPC call which would allow you to send a proto to that service, and retrieve any potential response proto you might produce.

When generating a proto called MyProto.proto using Google GRPC, a class called MyProtoServiceGrpc is automatically created. That class defines multiple static inner classes stubs that can be used by the client to make the calls to the service.

A GRPC client looks like this:

```
@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    log.debug("Connecting to {}", target);
    ManagedChannel managedChannel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(target)
            .usePlaintext().build();
    myProtoAsyncBlockingStub = MyProtoServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(managedChannel);
    myProtoServiceAsyncStub = MyProtoServiceGrpc.newStub(managedChannel);
}
```

Then, by calling either the blocking or async stub, you can send GRPC calls to the service located at the target:

```
public ResponseProto getResponse(RequestProto proto) {
    return myProtoServiceBlockingStub.getResponse(proto);
}
```